# How would I find the volume of a torus with an elliptical cross-section using calculus?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I know that, by Pappus' centroid theorem, the volume of a torus with an elliptic cross-section of major axis $a$ and minor axis $b$ is $2^2abc$, where $c$ is the distance from the center of the torus to the center of the elliptic cross-section. My doubt is how I would prove this using calculus?

What I have gotten so far is the parametric equations of the $x$, $y$, and $z$ co-ordinates of all the points in the elliptic torus, with the parameters being $u$ and $v$ ($v$ is the angle between the $a$ point and the $x$ or $y$ axes, and $u$ is the angle at which the cross-section has been rotated). It is:

$$
x(u, v) =  (c + a\cos v)\cos u$$
$$
y(u, v) = (c + a\cos v)\sin u$$
$$
z(u, v) = b\sin v$$

This is also what I get from [this source](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticTorus.html).

Using these parametric equations how can I derive the formula for the volume of a torus with an elliptic cross-section? I've seen many different things online such as using the Jacobian matrix but I am not too sure how to move on from here. Please help! **I'm a high school student so I don't know much.**

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You don't really need parametric equations for the surface to find the volume. This is a solid of revolution, so it's possible to compute the volume using the method of shells and also using the method of washers (slices, Cavalieri's Principle).

Comment: Hi! Could you briefly explain the method of shells and Cavalieri's Principle? These are all very new to me.

Comment: Hey thank you so much I just looked into the washer method and tried deriving it with that and I got it!! Thank you SO much!

Comment: You can find an explanation of Cavalieri's principle on Wikipedia. The method of washers and the method of shells are explained concisely on Wolfram Mathworld, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MethodofWashers.html. You can find worked examples by googling. Doing the volume of an elliptical torus is an advanced application of all these methos, so I recommend working through some easier examples first. **Congratulations on working this out. Post it as an answer to your own question so you can get feedback.**